# Cannot access second hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, files, nas

I am new to Ubuntu and I need a little help...

Recently, due to a power supply interruption, my Iomega NAS broke.
I've read that I was able to rescue the files that were on it by installing Ubuntu on a computer and attaching the hard drive from the NAS to it.

So yesterday, I installed Ubuntu on an old computer, the installation was successful. I can see my drive by using 'disk utility', but I can't access the files that are on it...

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Can someone help me out please?

EDIT: now using Ubuntu 14.04.1!

Result of lsblk

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN   RM      SIZE    R0      TYPE        MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0      149.1G    0     disk
 sda1    8:1    0      47.1G     0     disk        /media/Ubuntu
 sda2    8:2    0         1K     0     part
 sda5    8:5    0         2G     0     part(SWAP)
sdb      8:16   0    465.8 G     0     disk
  sdb1   8:17   0       3.9G     0     part
  sdb2   8:18   0     461.8G     0     part
  sdb3   8:19   0      23.5M     0     part
sdc      8:32   1       3.9G     0     disk
  sdc1   8:33   1       3.9G     0     part /cdrom
```

Comment: Well ubuntu 11.10 is pretty old could you try and update it?

Comment: OK, I'am creating a bootable usb now with Ubuntu version 14.04.1

Comment: OK, the installation of Ubuntu v.14.04.1 has finished. But I still can't acces my files... Could you help me out?

Comment: can you run a `lsblk` and show the output you can also try `sudo fdisk -l` to check which drives your system can see

Comment: Edit your question and put your output in the question not in a comment since its hard to read and its not formated correctly.

Comment: so the one you are trying to acces is the 465.8G sdb?

Comment: yes! My nas was 500 GB

Comment: can you print out this `sudo parted /dev/sdb print`

Comment: Basically the HDD is probably just not mounted so I believe if we assume the NAS to be some sort of *nix you should be able to mount the main partition using this: `mount /dev/sdb2 /media/'Insert Media Name'`

Comment: If I use mount /dev/sdb2 /media/' Insert Media Name', I get the message: "mount: only root can do that" Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo /dev/sdb2 /media/'Insert Media Name'` and change insert media name by the name you want like `sudo /dev/sdb2 /media/backup`

Comment: Now I'am getting the message "command not found"...

Comment: oh I forgot mount derp derp  here you go `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/backup`

Comment: Now I'am getting "mount: mount point /media/backup does not exist"

Comment: `sudo mkdir /media/backup`

Comment: I don't get any reaction on that comment..
After I've done it for the second time I get:" mkdir: cannot create directory 'media/backup' : File exists'

Comment: there isn't supposed to be a reaction `mkdir` makes a directory. And the second time it says that its created so now try to mount your drive on it.

Comment: Now I get the message :" mount: /dev/sdb2: can't read superblock"
I really appreciate your reactions!

Comment: can you run this `sudo file -s /dev/sdb2`

Comment: I'm getting "ERROR: cannot read '/dev/sdb2' (Input/Output error)"

Comment: Do you know the Filesystem used by that drive NFS, AFP, OES?

Comment: Message: Reading package lists ... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done The following extra packages wil be installed (a couple of packages are coming now, do I have to write them down?) ... After this operation 1,299 kB of additional disk space wil be used. Do you want to continue? I did Yes! Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trust/ main libgssglue1 i386 0.4-2ubuntu1 Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com' (Another couple of Err) E: unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? I really appreciate your answers. Thanks for all!

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21305/discussion-on-question-by-ubuntu-starter-cannot-access-second-hard-drive).

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if the system can see your disk with the `lsblk` command. if it does you need to gather the volume name from the command in your case its `sdb`. And the partition you want is `sdb2`.

Then if the system does not see it, it means that you have to mount it.

Create a mounting point:

```
sudo mkdir /media/sdb2
```

Mount the drive:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/sdb2
```

Repeat for any other partitions you care to mount (examples: sdb1, sdb3)

To make these permanent edit your /etc/fstab file